# Cartesian Product and Identity Function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Ok, I have this question:
[image]

Why do you have the id,id repeated twice? Does it define function on a function of an element in the set 2 like id(id(a E 2))?

Answer (score 2):

This is a [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)) (also known as a fibered product). In other words there is a cartesian square:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf 2 \times_{id,id} \mathbf 2 & \to & \mathbf 2 \\
\downarrow & \square & \downarrow id \\
\mathbf 2 & \xrightarrow{id} & \mathbf 2
\end{array}$$
In other other words, $\mathbf 2 \times_{id,id} \mathbf 2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbf 2 \times \mathbf 2 : id(x) = id(y) \}$.

---

In general, if $f : A \to C$ et $g : B \to C$, then $A \times_{f,g} B = \{ (x,y) \in A \times B : f(x) = g(y) \}$. It's also sometimes written as $A \times_C B$ when it's clear from the context what $f$ and $g$ are.